# Hosting a web application on discountasp.net using sql ce 5

Tags: hosting, sql-server-ce, discountasp

I am hoping that someone may have experience with this, since the discountasp site is very lacking in straightforward answers.

I am building a lightweight web application and have decided to have sql ce as the database for it. Two questions regarding this:

1. Do i need to get an actual database hosted as well as the site, in order for it to work?
2. Do you know if discountasp supports the use of sql ce (not with webmatrix or any cms builds, completely custom)? If they don't, do you have any experience/recommendations with getting this done?

Comment: You might get a better response on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I posted it there. How do I close this question??

Comment: Hi, I believe they do support SQL CE. You better ask their support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the host on discountAsp.net and use sql ce as the light-weight database.
In this case, you only need to host the website, no need for database hosting.
I use SQL ce 3.5 and it works fine.
But I encounter the problem when I upgrade the website to use ms sql ce 4.0 with EF. I am looking for the their support version for sql ce. So find your post.